# Javafx WebEngine: what really happens in a background worker? UI hangs on loadContent(big HTML document)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

From the [WebEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) docs:

> Loading always happens on a background thread. Methods that initiate
>   loading return immediately after scheduling a background job. To track
>   progress and/or cancel a job, use the Worker instance available from
>   the getLoadWorker() method.

I have an [HTML string](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B87_ZG258xnUZVVvczZFdFl3NmM/view?usp=sharing) which I load on the WebView via `WebEngine.loadContent(String)`. That string is about 5 million chars long. Upon running that in `Platform.runLater()` (and I have to run it in the JavaFX thread, otherwise I get an error) my UI hangs for about a minute.

If I don't run it in `Platform.runLater()` I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = populator
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.checkThread(WebEngine.java:1216)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.loadContent(WebEngine.java:931)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.loadContent(WebEngine.java:919)
    ...
```

I can't query the webEngine via `webEngine.getLoadWorker().getProgress()` nor cancel via `webEngine.getLoadWorker().cancel()` because I have to, again, run that on the JavaFX thread, which is hanged...

So I have to wait until the page loads, and then any `Platform.runLater(()->webEngine.getLoadWorker().getProgress())` submitted previously (during the webpage loading process) will run, giving me 1.0 each time...

The code I'm using to query the Worker:

```
// WebView
wvIn.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    class ProgressThread extends Thread {
        private Worker.State loadWorkerState;

        synchronized Worker.State getLoadWorkerState() {
            return loadWorkerState;
        }

        synchronized void setLoadWorkerState(Worker.State loadWorkerState) {
            this.loadWorkerState = loadWorkerState;
        }

        {
            setDaemon(true);
            setName("LoadingWebpageProgressThread");
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (getLoadWorkerState() == Worker.State.RUNNING)
                        // piWv ProgressIndicator (WebView loading)
                        Platform.runLater(() -> piWv.setVisible(true));
                    while (getLoadWorkerState() == Worker.State.RUNNING) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            piWv.setProgress(wvIn.getEngine().getLoadWorker().getProgress());
                            // TODO delete
                            System.out.println(wvIn.getEngine().getLoadWorker().getProgress());
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    if (getLoadWorkerState() == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> piWv.setProgress(1d));
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            piWv.setVisible(false);
                            piWv.setProgress(0d);
                        });
                    }
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    };

    final ProgressThread progressThread = new ProgressThread();
    {
        progressThread.start();
    }

    // executed on JavaFX Thread
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable, State oldValue, State newValue) {
        if (newValue == State.SUCCEEDED) {
            JSObject window = (JSObject) wvIn.getEngine().executeScript("window");
            window.setMember("controller", mainController);
            progressThread.setLoadWorkerState(newValue);
            progressThread.interrupt();
        } else if (newValue == State.RUNNING) {
            progressThread.setLoadWorkerState(newValue);
            progressThread.interrupt();
        }
        // TODO delete
        System.out.println(oldValue + "->" + newValue);
    }
});
```

Is there anyway to force the loading in a background thread?

What exactly is happening in the JavaFX thread? Is it the process of populating the WebView?

Comment: The documentation for `loadContent` says "As with load(String), this method is asynchronous", so I'm guessing you shouldn't be calling it with `Platform.runLater`. What error are you getting when calling it directly?

Comment: I edited the question to include what happens if I don't run it from the JavaFX thread.

Comment: This may be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151056/javafx-swing-browser-very-slow  - could be just a bug/performance issue with WebEngine...

Comment: @SlumpA There is an open issue regarding this: [WebView can only be created on the FX application thread](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087718). There also is an explanation about why it has to be run in app thread. I don't know if it's correct though.

Comment: When I make the call to loadContent the method returns immediately (as described in the docs). And that's ok, so I don't have a problem calling it from the JavaFX thread. What I think happens next is that the background worker does something, but not everything... My UI soon hangs after the call to loadContent is made.
What surprises me is that it seems that the majority of work is in fact done on the UI thread, and not on the background worker. That's annoying. As if the background worker's only job is just sending tasks to the JavaFX thread. I don't think that's what should be happening.

Comment: It would help if you let us see the HTML string in question.

Comment: I added a sample of the HTML string I'm using (as an html file) and the code to query the worker.
In this HTML I tried to put the style and the javascripte code at the end of the document, but I noticed no improvement in performance. The functionality remained same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That HTML file you showed in your question loads almost instantly on my machine.

In my opinion, the problem is in your code. Well, it's quite cumbersome. Please let me point out that it doesn't look very good, since it is [deadlock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html)-prone, and uses exceptions to implement a form of [guarded-blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

It looks like you don't fully understand the concept of [*events*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm#JFXED117).
Unless you have cut off the code snippet in your question in some way for the sake of brevity, the `ProgressThread` instance is completely useless.
You already have a [`ChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) dispatching events as needed, executing callbacks right on the JavaFX Application Thread; just use it.

```
indicator.setVisible(false); // Start hidden
engine.getLoadWorker().progressProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    indicator.setProgress(newValue.doubleValue());
    indicator.setVisible(indicator.getProgress() != 1D);
});
```

Alternatively, you could just use the power of [binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107):

```
Worker<Void> worker = engine.getLoadWorker();
indicator.visibleProperty().bind(worker.stateProperty().isEqualTo(Worker.State.RUNNING));
indicator.progressProperty().bind(worker.progressProperty());
```

For your JavaScript code, I suggest you to listen to document events instead of worker state events: they are more meaningful in your case, and they are fired when the page has actually finished rendering, not just when the page data has finished downloading.

```
engine.documentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue == null) {
        return;
    }
    JSObject window = (JSObject)engine.executeScript("window");
    window.setMember("controller", mainController);
});
```

Please note that on my machine, the progress appears always to be zero while loading is in progress. I think that the problem is in your HTML code: if you try to load some other resource, such us the webpage you are reading now, the progress indicator will deliver a much more enjoyable experience, being updated several times before the page contents have finished loading.

Comment: I agree that ProgressThread is useless. I implemented it so I could "ping" the loadWorker - to see what it was doing. Thank you for pointing out to me the documentProperty.
I'm a bit surprised that html loads almost instantly on your machine.
What I'm thinking of doing is to load just html without the body, and then via Javascript to progressively load the chunks of the body.

Comment: @SlumpA Which version of Java are you using? Have you tried removing the JavaScript injection code, to see if the problem persists?

Comment: jdk 1.8.0.101. By Javascript injection you mean: `JSObject window = (JSObject)engine.executeScript("window"); window.setMember("controller", mainController);`?

Comment: @SlumpA Yes, I mean that.

Comment: There was no notable performance difference by removing the javascript injection.

Answer (score 0):

So...

I ended up building my own Http Server to test `load` instead of `loadContent` (note: it's a bad server):

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class BadHttpServer {
    private static int request = 0, connection = 0;
    private static final BadHttpServer SINGLETON = new BadHttpServer();
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private String htmlString, formattedDate;
    private byte[] compressedHTML;

    public String getURL() {
        return "http://localhost:60000";
    }

    synchronized byte[] getCompressedHTML() {
        return compressedHTML;
    }

    synchronized void setCompressedHTML(String string) {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(string.length() / 2);
                GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);) {
            gos.write(string.getBytes("utf-8"));
            gos.close();
            this.compressedHTML = baos.toByteArray();
            formattedDate = String.format(Locale.US, "%1$ta, %1$td %1$tb %1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$tZ",
                    Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private synchronized String getFormattedDate() {
        return formattedDate;
    }

    private BadHttpServer() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(60000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Thread() {
            {
                setDaemon(true);
                setName("serverSocketThread");
            }

            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        new Thread(acceptAndSendHTML(serverSocket.accept())) {
                            {
                                setDaemon(true);
                                setName("acceptThread" + connection++);
                            }
                        }.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
        }.start();
    }

    protected Runnable acceptAndSendHTML(final Socket socket) {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "ASCII"));
                        BufferedWriter asciiWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "ASCII"));
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), 1000)) {
                    while (!socket.isClosed()) {
                        int request = BadHttpServer.request++;
                        // READING
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        stringBuilder.append(br.readLine() + "\r\n");
                        for (String line = ""; !(line = br.readLine()).isEmpty(); stringBuilder.append(line + "\r\n"))
                            ;
                        // TODO delete
                        System.out.print("Connection " + request + " request: " + stringBuilder);
                        // WRITING
                        byte[] compressedHTML = getCompressedHTML();
                        asciiWriter.write("HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\n");
                        asciiWriter.write("\r\n");
                        asciiWriter.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
                        asciiWriter.write("Date: " + getFormattedDate() + "\r\n");
                        asciiWriter.write("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n");
                        asciiWriter.write("Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n");
                        asciiWriter.write("Content-Charset: utf-8\r\n");
                        asciiWriter.write("Content-Length: " + compressedHTML.length + "\r\n");
                        // TODO delete
                        System.out.println("Content-Length: " + compressedHTML.length + "\r\n");
                        asciiWriter.write("\r\n");
                        asciiWriter.flush();
                        for (int writtenOverall = 0, writtenThisIteration = 0; writtenOverall < compressedHTML.length; writtenOverall += writtenThisIteration) {
                            bos.write(compressedHTML, writtenOverall,
                                    writtenThisIteration = Math.min(compressedHTML.length - writtenOverall, 1000));
                            Thread.sleep(10); // Bandwidth throttling
                        }
                        bos.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static BadHttpServer getIntance() {
        return SINGLETON;
    }

    public synchronized void setHtmlString(String htmlString) {
        this.htmlString = htmlString;
        setCompressedHTML(htmlString);
    }

    synchronized String getHtmlString() {
        return htmlString;
    }

}
```

And now, instead of `loadContent`, I'd

```
BadHttpServer.getIntance().setHtmlString(htmlString);
Platform.runLater(() -> wvIn.getEngine().load(BadHttpServer.getIntance().getURL()));
```

I did some benchmarks - measuring the time from once the loadWorker started `RUNNING` till it `SUCCEDED`:

```
via BadHttpServer:
javascript and style after body: 13,5 s
javascript and style before body: 8,6 s

so I continued to test with javascript and style before body.
without javascript injection: 8,5 s

I continued to test with javascript injection.

Next I did with loadContent: 170 s - no UI resposivness during loading
Yep - almost 3 minutes...

So I returned back with BadHttpServer.
Next I tried "throttling the bandwidth" by changing the sleep time.
no sleep: 8,2 s
5 ms sleep: 6,8 s
10 ms sleep: 6,7 s
20 ms sleep: 11,6 s

In these cases the UI was responsive, although it was lagging a bit.
The progressIndicator showed nicely, pausing a bit at 90%.
By increasing the sleep time, the UI was more responsive.
```

So, I'd guess the `loadContent` method could be a tad better, unless I'm doing something wrong implementing it...